# $A_{mn} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}d\theta\, \sin(2m\theta)\, \frac{1-\cos^{2n}(\theta)}{\tan(\theta)} = $ ? $m$, $n$ integers > 0

Tags: integration, fourier-series

The integral 
$$
A_{mn} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}d\theta\, \sin(2m\theta)\, \frac{1-\cos^{2n}(\theta)}{\tan(\theta)}
$$
popped up when I was playing around with the integral representation of the harmonic numbers $H_n$.

I find that Mathematica can give a result for specific values of $m$ and $n$ but I can't get a general formula. Some observations that appear to be true, based on Mathematica results for specific cases:

1) $A_{mn} > 0$.

2) When $m = n$, $A_{nn} = \frac{1}{4^n}$.

3) When $m > n$, $A_{mn} = 0$. (I think this should follow from expanding the $\cos^{2n}(\theta)$ part out in a finite sum of terms like $\sin$ or $\cos$ of integers times $\theta$.)

I tried doing this via contour integration by extending the integral (which is symmetric around $\pi$) to $[0,2\pi)$, and making the substitution $z = e^{i\theta}$. Unless I've made a mistake, this leads to:
$$
A_{mn} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint dz\,
\frac{\left(z^{2m} - z^{-2m}\right)\left(z+z^{-1}\right)\left[1 - \frac{1}{2^{2n}}{\left(z + z^{-1}\right)}^{2n}\right]}{z^2 - 1}\, ,
$$
where the integral is over the counter-clockwise unit circle. This doesn't seem to work: The zeroes appear to cancel on the top and bottom at $z = \pm 1$, so the residues are zero.

Have I made a mistake in the contour integration approach? Is there a better way to evaluate this whole thing?

Comment: The question started with "this integral" but didn't not say what the integral was or what $A_{mn}$ was. Don't assume that someone reading the post has read the title; the post itself should include all the necessary information.

Comment: @CarlMummert OK, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the identities $$\frac{\sin (2m \theta)}{\sin (\theta)} = 2 \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \cos[(2k+1)\theta]$$

and

[$$\cos^{2n+1}(\theta) = \frac{1}{4^{n}}\sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{j} \cos [2n+1-2j)\theta], $$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricPowerFormulas.html) we get

$$ \begin{align} A_{mn} &= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin (2 m \theta)}{\sin (\theta)}\left(\cos (\theta) - \cos^{2n+1}(\theta) \right) \, d \theta \\ &= \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos[(2k+1)\theta] \cos(\theta) \, d \theta \\ &- \frac{2}{\pi} \, \frac{1}{4^{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{j}\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos[(2k+1)\theta ] \cos[(2n+1-2j) \theta] \, d \theta.  \end{align} $$

First assume that $m <n$.

Then using the fact that

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(mx) \cos(nx) \, dx = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{\pi}{2}  & m = n \\
     0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases} $$ we get

$$A_{mn} = \frac{2}{\pi} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}  \right) - \frac{2}{\pi} \, \frac{1}{4^{n}} \sum_{j=n-m+1}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{j} \frac{\pi}{2} = 1 - \frac{1}{4^{n}} \sum_{j=n-m+1}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{j}.  $$

Now if $m> n$, then

$$ A_{mn} = \frac{2}{\pi} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \right)- \frac{2}{\pi} \, \frac{1}{4^{n}} \sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{j} \frac{\pi}{2}  = 1 - \frac{1}{4^{n}} \left(4^{n}\right) = 0. \tag{1}$$

And if $m=n$,  $$A_{mn} = 1- \frac{1}{4^{n}} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{j} = 1 - \frac{1}{4^{n}} \left(4^{n}-1\right) = \frac{1}{4^{n}}.  $$

---

$(1)$ [Prove the identity $\binom{2n+1}{0} + \binom{2n+1}{1} + \cdots + \binom{2n+1}{n} = 4^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1607936/16033)

Comment: @joriki I added an extra line to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> **The Question**:
>   $\ds{A_{mn} \equiv
> {1 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\pars{2m\theta}\,
> {1 - \cos^{2n\,}\pars{\theta} \over \tan\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta\,,\qquad
> m,n \in \braces{1,2,3,\ldots}}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{A_{mn}} & =
{1 \over 2\pi}\,\Im\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\expo{2m\ic\theta}\,
{1 - \cos^{2n\,}\pars{\theta} \over \tan\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm] & =
{1 \over 2\pi}\,\Im\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}z^{2m}\,
{1 \over -\ic\pars{z^{2} - 1}/\pars{z^{2} + 1}}\,
\bracks{1 - \pars{z^{2} + 1 \over 2z}^{2n}}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}
\\[3mm] & =
{1 \over 2\pi}\,{1 \over 2^{2n}}\Im\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}z^{2m - 2n - 1}\,\,\,
{z^{2} + 1 \over z^{2} - 1}\,
\bracks{2^{2n}z^{2n} - \pars{z^{2} + 1}^{2n}}\,\dd z\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

Indeed, as the OP already claimed there isn't any poles at $\ds{z = \pm 1}$. So, we concentrate our efforts with poles $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{it depends on the particular values of}\ m\ \mbox{and}\ n ~}}$ at $\ds{z = 0}$. It amounts to rewrite $\ds{\pars{1}}$ in a convenient way. Namely,
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{A_{mn}} & =
{1 \over 2\pi}\,{1 \over 2^{2n}}\Im\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
\pars{z^{2m + 1}\ +\ z^{2m - 1}\ }
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}z^{2\ell}\
\bracks{\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose \ell'}z^{2\pars{\ell' - n}} - 2^{2n}}
\,\dd z
\\[8mm] & =
{1 \over 2\pi}\,{1 \over 2^{2n}}\Im\bracks{%
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\,\,\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose \ell'}
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}\,\frac{\dd z}{z^{2n - 2\ell' - 2\ell - 2m - 1}}\,\,}
\\[3mm] & +
{1 \over 2\pi}\,{1 \over 2^{2n}}\Im\bracks{%
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\,\,\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose \ell'}
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}\,\frac{\dd z}{z^{2n - 2\ell' - 2\ell - 2m + 1}}\,\,}
\\[3mm] & -
{1 \over 2\pi}\,{1 \over 2^{2n}}\Im\bracks{%
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\underbrace{%
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}\,\frac{\dd z}{z^{-2n - 2\ell - 2m - 1}}\,\,}
_{\ds{= 0}}} -
{1 \over 2\pi}\,{1 \over 2^{2n}}\Im\bracks{%
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\underbrace{%
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}\,\frac{\dd z}{z^{-2n - 2\ell - 2m + 1}}\,\,}
_{\ds{=\ 0}}}
\\[8mm] & =
{1 \over 2^{2n}}\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose \ell'}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
\delta_{\ell,n - \ell' - m - 1}\,\,\,\, +
{1 \over 2^{2n}}\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose \ell'}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
\delta_{\ell,n - \ell' - m}
\\[3mm] & =
\left.{1 \over 2^{2n}}\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose \ell'}
\right\vert_{\ \ell'\ \leq\ n - m - 1} +
\left.{1 \over 2^{2n}}\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose \ell'}
\right\vert_{\ \ell'\ \leq\ n - m}
\\[3mm] & =
\color{#f00}{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{ccrcl}
\ds{{1 \over 4^{n}}\bracks{-{2n \choose n - m} + 2\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{n - m}{2n \choose \ell'}}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{m} & \ds{<} & \ds{n}
\\[2mm]
\ds{1 \over 4^{n}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{m} & \ds{=} & \ds{n}
\\[2mm]
\ds{0} & \mbox{if} & \ds{m} & \ds{>} & \ds{n}
\end{array}\right.}
\end{align}